# How can i print a specific value in matrix in python? (Using numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I got this code which prints a zero matrix given the size (m x n). But i wanna extract a specific value in a specific location of that matrix but i've tried everything i know and it's still not working. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np 

class Matrix:

def __init__(self, m, n):
  self.row = m
  self.column = n

def define_matrix(self):
  return np.zeros((self.row, self.column), dtype=int)

def __str__(self):
  return self.define_matrix()

def get(self, a, b):
  try:
    if not a in range(self.row+1):
      print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
    elif not b in range(self.column+1):
      print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
    else:
      print(
        'El valor ubicado en la fila {} '
        'y en la columna {} es: {}'
        .format(a, b, self.define_matrix()[a - 1][b - 1]))
  except:
    print('Ingrese datos válidos')

def set(self, value, a, b):
  matrix1 = self.define_matrix()
  if not a in range(self.row+1):
    print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
  elif not b in range(self.column+1):
    print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
  else:
    matrix1[a-1][b-1] = value
    return matrix1

a = Matrix(4, 4) # matrix could be any size
a.set(80, 1, 3)
a.get(1, 3)
```

and here´s what i get:

[image: console image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 

class Matrix:

def __init__(self, m, n):
  self.row = m
  self.column = n

def define_matrix(self):
  return np.zeros((self.row, self.column), dtype=int)

def __str__(self):
  return self.define_matrix()

def get(self, a, b):
  try:
    if not a in range(self.row+1):
      print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
    elif not b in range(self.column+1):
      print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
    else:
      print(
        'El valor ubicado en la fila {} '
        'y en la columna {} es: {}'
        .format(a, b, self.define_matrix()[a - 1][b - 1]))
        #             is a matrix of zeros.
  except:
    print('Ingrese datos válidos')

def set(self, value, a, b):
  matrix1 = self.define_matrix()
  if not a in range(self.row+1):
    print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
  elif not b in range(self.column+1):
    print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
  else:
    matrix1[a-1][b-1] = value
    return matrix1 # outputs matrix, but is never saved in Matrix object
    # to solve this, you need to save matrix1 in a variable in Matrix
    # instead of returning it

a = Matrix(4, 4) # matrix could be any size
a.set(80, 1, 3) # not saved in a variable - code executes but return value is discarded
a.get(1, 3)
```

Here is the modified code:

```
import numpy as np 

class Matrix:
    
    def __init__(self, m, n):
      self.row = m
      self.column = n
      self.matrix1 = np.zeros((self.row, self.column), dtype=int)

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.matrix1) # EDIT: forgot to modify this line.
      # fatal mistake on my part :(

    def get(self, a, b):
      try:
        if not a in range(self.row+1):
          print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
        elif not b in range(self.column+1):
          print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
        else:
          print(
            'El valor ubicado en la fila {} '
            'y en la columna {} es: {}'
            .format(a, b, self.matrix1[a - 1][b - 1]))
      except:
        print('Ingrese datos válidos')

    def set(self, value, a, b):
      if not a in range(self.row+1):
        print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
      elif not b in range(self.column+1):
        print('El valor deseado no pertenece a la matriz.')
      else:
        self.matrix1[a-1][b-1] = value
        return self.matrix1

a = Matrix(4, 4) # matrix could be any size
a.set(80, 1, 3)
a.get(1, 3)
```

I apologize if I got anything wrong as I don't understand Spanish.

Comment: Thank you soo so much!! it's perfectly working now 

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are calling `self.define_matrix()[a - 1][b - 1])` within the `get` method.

Because of that, no matter which value you insert in your matrix using the `set` method, what you end up showing is the '0' created upon instantiating the matrix with `np.zeros((self.row, self.column), dtype=int)`.

Comment: Thanksss!! that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(np.ones((5, 5)))
```

You can the change the matrix dimensions as you like.